# Add a number to the end of a sublist?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I need to delete the second item in the second sublist and then add the number 500 to the end of the second sublist. The list is:

```
list = [[100,200],[300,400]]
```

end result should be:

```
list = [[100,200],[300,500]]
```

is there a way to do this without doing the following?:

```
del list[1]
list.append([300,500])
```

I tried this but it returned an index error:

```
list[1][1]=500
```

and so did this:

```
list.insert(([1][1]),500)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If list[1][1] returns an index error, the list you are working on does not match the one in the question. position 1,1 clearly exists in your example

Answer (score 1):

If the element already exists, you can simply overwrite it:

```
mylist = [[100,200],[300,400]]  
mylilst[1][1] = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete anything, just reassign. This is a typical pattern in programming.

```
list = [[100,200],[300,400]]
list[1][1] = 500
print(list)
```

outputs

```
[[100,200],[300,500]]
```

as desired.

Btw, `list` is a Python built-in. Better to call the variable `lst`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

like @James and @Matt mentioned,

```
>>> list[1][1] = 500 
[[100, 200], [300, 500]]
```

will overwrite your data as expected.

But if for some reason you want to remove and add data (instead of overwriting):

```
>>> list = [[100,200],[300,400]]
>>> list[1].pop()
[[100, 200], [300]]
>>> list[1].append(500)
[[100, 200], [300, 500]]
```

Comment: this worked! why does list[1].pop() delete just 400, and not the entire sublist [300,400]? why wouldn't list[1][1].pop() work instead (specifying second item in second sublist)?

Comment: list[1] relates to the second list inside main list ([300, 500]). by using .pop() on list[1] we remove from that specific list. 
list[1][1] relates to the VALUE (integer 500). and you cannot call "pop()" method on a integer number. pop() works on lists, not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

OR the below, (will do the last element of any length sequence):

```
>>> list = [[100,200],[300,400]]
>>> list[-1][-1]=500
>>> list
[[100,200],[300,500]]
```

By the way, also see this image:

[image]

Also see:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
   0   1   2   3   4   5 
  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Comment: lol, what is that image representing? did you wrote it with a stick ? :)